# How to suppress auto-searching when subclassing combobox (Win32/WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox, subclassing

I want to make a custom search but it's crippled by auto search. Here is what I mean,

This is my subclassing function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK X(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam,UINT_PTR r1,DWORD_PTR r2)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if(wParam>64&&wParam<91) //if A-Z hit
            {
                char a[2];
                a[0]=wParam;
                insearch.append(a);
            }
            else if(wParam==27) insearch=""; //esc key
            else if(wParam==8&&insearch.length()) insearch.erase(insearch.length()-1,1); //backspace
            SendMessage(hwnd,CB_SETCURSEL,SendMessage(hwnd,CB_FINDSTRING,-1,LPARAM(insearch.c_str())),0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

And this is main WM_CREATE message switch,

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    CreateWindowEx(0,"combobox",0,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|CBS_DROPDOWNLIST|WS_VSCROLL,5,5,90,125,hwnd,HMENU(1),0,0);
    char o[][20]={"Fauna","Fiat","Fold","Folk","Fall","Fires","Ant"};
    for(char i=0; i<7; i++) SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,1,CB_ADDSTRING,0,LPARAM(o[i]));
    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,1,CB_SETCURSEL,0,0);
    SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd,1),X,0,0);
    break;
}
```

I have a global variable `std::string insearch;` and each time a letter key is hit, it is changed and used for searching. It works well backwards but it doesn't work as intended forwards. For example when `insearch=="FIR"` it selects `"Fires"` and once <kbd>←</kbd> is hit `insearch=="FI"` and it highlights `"Fiat"` correctly and once again <kbd>←</kbd> is hit `insearch=="F"` and it highlights `"Fauna"` as intended. Because <kbd>←</kbd> doesn't interfere with autosearch but letter keys do. If then <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed and `insearch=="FA"`, it highlights `"Ant"` by default. Because auto searching depends on just one char and it is `"A"` and it searches for something starts with `"A"`, but I want it to skip that default search and go for my custom way which should highlight `"Fauna"` because `"FA"` is in search. So this is the situation, please suggest me a way to suppress the automatic search.

Comment: Doesn't look like this would be C...

Comment: Notice that you're always calling the default proc too. Perhaps you wanted to suppress calling the default proc in case it is keydown?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I guess that might help but how to do it?

Comment: `return` instead of `break`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I now tried returning both 1 and 0, default proc still is being called.

Comment: Maybe it happens on keyup? :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I tried adding `case WM_KEYUP: return 1;` but no effect :/

Comment: Is your space key broken? o.O

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much, I returned 1 from `WM_CHAR` and it doesn't auto select now. I'll move my custom selector into it and I think that'll work :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does work. If you could post your comment as an answer, I would gladly mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @user814412 posted

Comment: The system provides the infrastructure to implement autocomplete, so that you don't have to roll your own. See [Using Autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776884(v=vs.85)) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Default Combo Box Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/combo-box-features#default-combo-box-behavior), the default search behavior is triggered in response to `WM_CHAR`, not `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)`:

> WM_CHAR
> Processes character input. In drop-down list boxes, this message is passed to the list window, **which moves the selection to the first item beginning with the specified character**. In simple and drop-down combo boxes, this message is passed to the edit control.